# laravel 5.2 auth doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, csrf

hi there i got a super weir auth login my application work just fine like 6 month but 1 day user and i can't login anymore

after login i got

```
     TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

so i try add exception url on  VerifyCrsftoken like this

```
      protected $except = [
          '/login'
      ];
```

and now i got redirect loop after login back to login page again my guess is auth  is return false both the correct email/password or not it super weir and i don't know what cause it can anyone help me?

route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
    Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('admin/tour', 'AdminController@tour');
});
```

admincontroller.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\Booktour;
use App\Bookcustomer;
use App\Bookdiscount;
use App\Booktourpay;
use App\Customerorder;
use App\Tourdetail;
use App\Tourperiod;
use App\Tourlead;
use Session;
use View;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use Datetime;
use DB;
use Image;
use App\User;

    class AdminController extends Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $count_customer = Bookcustomer::count();    
            $getuser = Auth::user()->name;
            $booking_order = Booking::where('sales_name', '=',$getuser)
                                            ->orderby('created_at', 'DSEC')
                                            ->get();    
            $booktour_open = DB::table('tourlist')->where('status' ,'=', 'เปิดขาย')->count();
            $tour = Booktour::where('status', 'เปิดขาย')
                                    ->orderby('depart_date', 'asc')
                                    ->get();
            $unpaid = Booking::where('sales_name', '=', $getuser)
                                    ->where('status', 'รอเงินโอน')
                                    ->count();      

            $allbook_list = Booking::where('status', '=', "รอเงินโอน")->orderby('created_at', 'DSEC')->get();   
            $today_date = strtotime('now');     
            $payment_list = Booktourpay::Today()->get();

            $user_list_payment = Booktourpay::where('create_by', '=', $getuser)->get();

            return view('admin.home')
            ->with('booking_order', $booking_order)
            ->with('count_customer', $count_customer)
            ->with('booktour_open', $booktour_open)
            ->with('tour', $tour)
            ->with('unpaid', $unpaid)
            ->with('allbook_list', $allbook_list)
            ->with('payment_list', $payment_list)
            ->with('user_list_payment', $user_list_payment);
        }
```

auth.php

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

im try to upgread to 5.2 and still doesn't work :/

EDIT after or before login or acces login page i got this redirectpage what caused this? 
http://postimg.org/image/pcvuyonah/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove Route::auth() from the route group that contains the auth middleware.

Comment: try it and it doesn't work and i got redirect page after login like this
"Redirecting to http://xxxxxxxxxx/public/login." 
it like auth session get reset after redirecting